# Vectors notation in Equation

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors

I have two vectors $\bf a$ and $\bf b$. Each time I use a fixed value for  $\bf a$ (i.e. not a vector) and a vector $\bf b$ or a vector $\bf a$ and fix value for $\bf b$ (i.e. not a vector).

The equation has the following form:

\begin{equation}
W(a,b)= W_0(ke^{- {\bf a}r_1-{\bf b}r_2}+ (1-k)e^{- {\bf a}r_3-{\bf b}r_4})
\end{equation}

where $k ,r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ are constants.

My question is the following. Is the above notation correct or should I have to write the above equation like this?
\begin{equation}
W({\bf a},{\bf b})= W_0(ke^{- {\bf a}r_1-{\bf b}r_2}+ (1-k)e^{- {\bf a}r_3-{\bf b}r_4})
\end{equation}

Comment: What's $e^{\mathbf{v}}$ where $\mathbf{v}$ is a vector?

Comment: I edited the equation because I didn't include the second part of it.Sorry I didn't understand your question. What do you mean what is $e^{\bf v}$.

Comment: Your equation involves $e^{- {\bf a}r_1-{\bf b}r_2}$, but ${- {\bf a}r_1-{\bf b}r_2}$ is a vector.  Egreg (and I) does not understand what that means.

Comment: This is actually my question because I am not sure how to write this correctly. What I did actually I took the above equation and once I used a single fix value for a (not a vector) and I used a vector $\bf b$. After that I used a vector $\bf a$ and a single value for b. Does this make sense?